# udp ping client and server python codes not printing anything/communicating

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have been trying to code a upd client and server in python. I have provided my code here. when I run the client and server files, I get no error message and I also dont get any output. I have done a lot of research but I cant seem to figure out how to get this to work. Please help!

my Server code is here

```
from socket import *
import random


def main():
    Ssocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    Ssocket.bind(('', 2014))
    print("I will be waiting on port" , 2014)

    while True:
        RandNum = random.randint(0,10)
        data , clientAddress = Ssocket.recvfrom(1024)
        newData =  data.upper()



        if randNum < 4:
            print ("packet lost")
            continue

        Ssocket.sendto(newData, clientAddress)
    main()
```

and my client code is below

```
from socket import*
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

def main():
    print (" the program is running  ")

    serverName = 'localhost'
    port = 2014
    Csocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = ' ping'
    #data = input("Enter a message in lowercase")

    LastPing = 10
    count = 0
    Csocket.settimeout(1)
    print ("Attempting to send " , count , "messages" )

    while count  < LastPing:
        count = count + 1
        startTime = time.time()
        print("The current time is: " , startTime , " and this is message
              number: " , count)
        Csocket.sendto(data, (serverName, port))

        try:
            newData, clientAddress = Csocket.recvfrom(1024)
            RTT = ((time.time()) - startTime)
            print (newData)
            print (RTT)
        except socket.timeout:
            print(" Request timed out ")
    print ("the program is done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify server code and client code as below:
Server.py

```
from socket import *
import random
def main():
    ssocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    ssocket.bind(('', 2014))
    print("I will be waiting on port" , 2014)

    while True:
        RandNum = random.randint(0,10)
        data , clientAddress = ssocket.recvfrom(1024)
        newData =  data.upper()



        if RandNum < 4:
            print ("packet lost")
            continue

        ssocket.sendto(newData, clientAddress)
main()
```

Client.py

```
from socket import *
import datetime
import time

def main():
    serverName = 'localhost'
    port = 2014
    Csocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = ' ping'
    #data = input("Enter a message in lowercase")

    LastPing = 10
    count = 0
    Csocket.settimeout(1)
    print ("Attempting to send " , count , "messages" )

    while count  < LastPing:
        count = count + 1
        startTime = time.time()
        print("The current time is: " , startTime , " and this is message number: " , count)
        Csocket.sendto(data, (serverName, port))

        try:
            newData, clientAddress = Csocket.recvfrom(1024)
            RTT = ((time.time()) - startTime)
            print (newData)
            print (RTT)
        except timeout:
            print(" Request timed out ")
        except Exception as e:
            print e
    print ("the program is done")
main()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I got this error:                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\COMP 430\Python Programs\testCLient.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\COMP 430\Python Programs\testCLient.py", line 21, in main
    Csocket.sendto(data, (serverName, port))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: If you are using python 3, use `data.encode('ascii')` instead of data while sending, and while reading/printing use `data.decode('ascii')`

Comment: Thank you. after a long struggle with this issue i finally solved it by uninstalling my python and pyscripter because part of the issue was because I was using python gui and a non corresponding pyscripter. I then installed python 2.7.5 and pyscripter 2.5.3. ran the server in the pyscripter and client in python shell. worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

finally solved it by uninstalling my python and pyscripter because part of the issue was because I was using python gui and a non corresponding pyscripter. I then installed python 2.7.5 and pyscripter 2.5.3. ran the server in the pyscripter and client in python shell. worked fine for me!